# Визуализация алгоритма “SQRT декомпозиция”

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, pyqt5, визуализация

Есть структура данных SqrtDecompositor. В ней массив разбивается на куски, а размер каждого из кусков равен sqrt(n). Реализованы методы для нахождения минимальго, максимального элементов и суммы элементов на определенном участке массива.

Требуется написать визулизатор данного алгоритма при помощи PyQt.

Программа визуализатор должна уметь:

- заполнять список элементов либо случайным образом, либо вручную пользователем
- перемещаться по алгоритму шагами вперед и назад.

Сама визуализация должна выглядеть следующим образом (для нахождения минимума):

1. На первом шаге выводится весь список элементов, например 3 4 2 0 -1 6 5 9 1;
2. далее происходит графическое выделение кусков списка, в данном случае 342|0-16|591;
3. далее происходит визуализация и отщепление минимума в каждом из кусков, в данном случае 2 -1 1, из которых делается новый кусок из минимумов и выполняется операция по нахождения самого наименьшего из них.

Сам код алгоритма:

```
class SqrtDecompositor(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        assert len(source) > 0
        self.batch_size = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(source))))
        self.batch_mins = tuple(
            map(lambda x: min(source[x: x + self.batch_size]),
                range(0, len(source), self.batch_size))
        )
        self.source = source[:]

    def min(self, a, b):
        assert a < b
        batch_a = a // self.batch_size + 1
        batch_b = b // self.batch_size
        if batch_a > batch_b:
            return min(self.source[a: b])
        return min(itertools.chain(
            self.source[a: batch_a * self.batch_size],
            self.batch_mins[batch_a: batch_b],
            self.source[batch_b * self.batch_size: b],
        ))

    def max(self, a, b):
        assert a < b
        batch_a = a // self.batch_size + 1
        batch_b = b // self.batch_size
        if batch_a < batch_b:
            return max(self.source[a: b])
        return max(itertools.chain(
            self.source[a: batch_a * self.batch_size],
            self.batch_mins[batch_a: batch_b],
            self.source[batch_b * self.batch_size: b],
        ))

    def sum(self, a, b):
        assert a < b
        batch_a = a // self.batch_size + 1
        batch_b = b // self.batch_size
        if batch_a < batch_b:
            return sum(self.source[a: b])
        return sum(itertools.chain(
            self.source[a: batch_a * self.batch_size],
            self.batch_mins[batch_a: batch_b],
            self.source[batch_b * self.batch_size: b],
        ))
```

Сам интерфейс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос в чем ? где возникли трудности ?

Comment: Проблема в не понимании, как реализовать визуализацию штатными средствами pyqt данного алгоритма.